# Is limit a value or a representation technique/notation?

Tags: limits

- $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)),

> A limit is the **value** that a function (or sequence) "approaches" as the input (or index) "approaches" some value.

According to the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-2/a/limits-intro),

> Limits **describe** how a function behaves near a point, instead of at that point.

Is limit a value or a representation technique/notation?

Comment: The first definition is more correct.  The second is more of a heuristic.  A limit is a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both.  But "limit" is not the only place we say things two ways.

Does $3+4$  mean the process of adding $3$ and $4$, or does it mean the result of that addition?  We can say "The first summand in $3+4$ is odd".  But we can also say "$3+4$ is a prime number".

We can say "The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ converges."  But we can also say "$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ is irrational".